# Display most recent post in full, excerpts of older posts

Tags: posts, excerpt

Running 3.5.1. Is there an easy way to display my most recent post in its entirety and only display excerpts for my older posts on my home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basic idea behind what you want. Extend/Customize to your liking.

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        the_title();
        // Incrementing a not instantiated variable results in 1
        // so there's no need to set it to 0 beforehand
        if ( 0 < $is_first_post++ ) the_excerpt();
        else the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Or if you want to ommit the compare and the increment operations:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

**// EDIT** to get the one-and-only most recent post in full only:

```
if (have_posts()) {
    if (2 > get_query_var('paged')) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for example, but won't your second example show both `the_content()` and `the_excerpt()` of the first post?

Comment: No, it does not. Within the loop I first fetch the next post and then print the title and excerpt.

Comment: Ah, of course, `the_post()` will do the job as required.

Comment: Thank you, T F. That does work, however, it seems to get rid of my 'Read more' link following the excerpts...?

Comment: Hm? Why is that? Whatever you put inside the `while` loop should get called (and thus be displayed). If you still have the problem, and with removing the above code everything is working fine, maybe post a new question, so you can provide us with your code. I'm positive we find a solution for your problem.

Comment: My mistake, t f - it actually does work if you write the code correctly which I hadn't done the first time around. However, I don't know if I'm still overlooking something but right now the first post on each page displays in full, whereas I only want the most recent post to display in full. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hey @Jane, please see my updated answer. I didn't understand 'most recent' _globally_, meaning the 'one-and-only most recent post'. ;)

Comment: OK thanks so much for all your help, t f. This definitely got me on the right track and I was able to get it to work! :)

Comment: Where does one put this logic? Is this within some function in the functions.php file for the installed theme? Apologies for the newbie question.